# Eclipse PDE: dynamic StyleRange

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt

I need an ability to select a part of the text in the editor with some new background for example.
StyleRange works fine but as the text is modified the applied style is dropped.
Is there any solution that allows StyleRange entity to track document changes and redraw applied styles on the fly? I'd need a solution like RangeHighlighter in Intellij IDEA.

Comment: An editor based on what? TextEditor? TextEditor supports various styling options such as AnnotationModel, PresentationReconciler, Damager/Repairer, ....

Comment: Based on TextEditor. Thank you for the hint, a new annotation with type FOCUS_ANNOTATION_TYPE is what we need.